# How to display error message if member doesn't have permissions? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a simple clear command & have it return an error message if the member does not have the manage messages permission.

```
@bot.command()  
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)  
async def clear(ctx, amount=10):  
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
@bot.command()   
async def clear(ctx, amount = 10): 
    authorperms = ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.channel)
    if authorperms.manage_messages:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    else:
        await ctx.send("You don't have the permissions to do that!")
```

There is probably a better way of doing this by using the Exception raised when someone without the right permissions tries to use the command, or by overwriting the on_error method but I don't know how. This should fix the problem for you until you can find a better solution.