# You do not have permission to use this command Discord.py Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in discord.py rewrite and I am trying to use a line of code to detect if a user has permission to use a command.

I would like to display an error message if the user does not have the permissions. I'm using this code but it won't work.

```
@client.command(aliases=['c'])
async def clear(ctx,amount=2):
  perms = ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.channel)
  if perms.manage_messages:
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = 1)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
    em = discord.Embed(description = f"Successfully cleared {amount} messages", color = discord.Colour.red())
    await ctx.send(embed = em, delete_after=3)
  else:
    em = discord.Embed(title = "Permissions Required!", description = f"{ctx.author.name} You do not have the required Permissions to use this command", color = discord.Colour.red())
    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

I don't get any errors on my server when I use it. when my discord mods try to use it they get the error message even though they have permissions.

I know I can use `@commands.has_permission()` but I want an error msg.

Comment: I made an answer to that a while ago. Is the following helping you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67274688/handle-error-when-passing-a-wrong-type-argument-to-a-command/67274811#67274811

Comment: I tried using it does not work for me. Is there a way I get get my permissions code working

Comment: I use the code from this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60246246/how-to-display-error-message-if-member-doesnt-have-permissions-discord-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to request the permissions in another/easier way. What you missed is `guild`.

**Simply use:**

```py
if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
```

A **full code** could be:

```py
@client.command(aliases=['c'])
async def clear(ctx, amount=2):
    if ctx.message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
        em = discord.Embed(description=f"Successfully cleared {amount} messages", color=discord.Colour.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=em, delete_after=3)
    else:
        em = discord.Embed(title="Permissions Required!",
                           description=f"{ctx.author.name} You do not have the required Permissions to use this command",
                           color=discord.Colour.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very similar question for [Can't get discord.py to raise an error if user doesn't have permissions to kick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234166/cant-get-discord-py-to-raise-an-error-if-user-doesnt-have-permissions-to-kick)

```
@_kick.error
async def kick_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f'Please pass in all requirements {ctx.message.author.mention} :rolling_eyes:.')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f"You dont have all the requirements {ctx.message.author.mention} :angry:")
```

OR

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    await ctx.send("You do not have the permissions required for this command.")
    return
```

OR

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description="An error has been occured!", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_author(name="YourBot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879295069834850324/Avatar.png")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879298565380386846/sign-red-error-icon-1.png")
    embed.add_field(name="Error", value="You don't have the permissions required to use this command!", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return

  if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="ERROR", description="An error has been occured!", color=0xff0000)
    embed.set_author(name="YourBot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879295069834850324/Avatar.png")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879298565380386846/sign-red-error-icon-1.png")
    embed.add_field(name="Error", value="You haven't passed the needed arguments for this command to run properly", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Possible Fix", value="use `{bot_prefix}help all` to list out all the command and check the proper usage of the command you used", inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
```

In the last snippet is the code that i used and it is a combination of both the first and the second snippets in this answer